# Why HttpConnection could be used even after the related HTTPResponse closed

Tags: python

See the following code, written in Python 2.7

```
import httplib

HOST, PORT, PATH = '127.0.0.1', 8888, '/'  # mask


def test():
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(HOST, PORT)
    conn.request('GET', PATH, None, headers={})
    rsp = conn.getresponse()
    print rsp.status
    rsp.close()  # close response

    conn.request('GET', PATH, None, headers={})
    rsp2 = conn.getresponse()
    print rsp2.status


test()
```

The server will always return **403** for testing. But the result of test() is

> 403 200

It looks so wired! Two questions here

1. Why the connection still could be used even after closing the
   **HTTPResponse**, does the underlying socket closed?
   *It seemed that the underling socket does not shutdown.*
2. Why **200** is returned?

Here are the server code using Tornado

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.set_status(403)
        self.write('<html>\r\nhello world\r\n</html>')

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are **closing** a file on top of the socket and not the socket.

Quote from the documentation for `socket.makefile`

> Return a file object associated with the socket. (File objects are
>   described in File Objects.) The file object does not close the socket
>   explicitly when its close() method is called, but only removes its
>   reference to the socket object, so that the socket will be closed if
>   it is not referenced from anywhere else.

Link: https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html

And the `close` in `HTTPResponse` closes `self.fp` which is the result of `self.fp = sock.makefile(...` in the `__init__` method of `HTTPResponse` in `httplib`

The socket is still referenced in your `conn` object and hence it will not be automatically closed.

(some people would say: *Use the source Luke* )

As to why the server returns `200`... you would need to let the world know against what you are testing and how the communication (HTTP Content) looks like.

Edit following the comment:

`HTTPResponse.close` does not consume anything. It simply removes a reference to to the socket, but you still have a reference in `conn`.

The data remains in the socket's buffer until the socket is really closed.

You are getting `200`, because the 2nd `getresponse` tries to parse the data in the buffer. And because no proper *HTTP Status* line is found (it was consumed by the 1st `getresponse`), the result is that `HTTPResponse` believes it is an old HTTP 0.9 server and sets the default answer code to `200`.

The code is in `HTTPResponse._read_status`

Comment: It seems that httplib did not consume all remaining body when calling HTTPResponse.close()

Comment: I think HTTPResponse should read the remaining body when calling close() to make sure the request complete.

Comment: You may think *it should* but it **does not** and the documentation clearly states what `close`  does